# How use if in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache

I use .htaccess for Friendly URL, but i have a problem. My subdomain store.domain.com  redirect to "/" but, default file is "store.php" and domain.com redirect to "/", default file is "index.php"

i need use if, for example

```
<If host == 'store.domain.com'>
 store rewrite rules
<If host == 'domain.com'>
 other rewrite rules different of store
</if>
```

How i do in .htaccess??

My Htaccess:

```
IndexIgnore *

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ store.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ store.php?page=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ store.php?page=$1&action=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ store.php?page=$1&action=$2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try and research your problem a little more before posting a question on Stack Overflow next time. A simple web search of your problem brings up `RewriteCond` statements. Then you could refer to the [Apache mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/).

This documentation would lead you to results, such as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^store.example.com$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ store.php?page=$1
```